# Is there an easy way to change a char in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, char

I want to do this:

```
string s = "abc";
s[1] = 'x';
```

and s will become "axc". However, it seems that string[i] only has a getter and has no setter. The compiler gives me the following error:

> "Property or indexer
>   'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned
>   to -- it is read only"

I guess I could make a loop and change the char i want. but i was just wondering if there is an easy way to do it? And why there isn't a setter for string[i]?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strings in C# are immutable so you can't do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you have to make a `char[]` array, change it, then make it back into a string:

```
string s = "foo";
char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
arr[1] = 'x';
s = new string(arr);
```

Answer (score 13):

Strings are immutable which is why there's no setter, you can however use a string builder:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("abc");

s[1] = 'x';
```

Answer (score 2):

(Your example is slightly wrong: s[2] = 'x' should change it to "abx".)

No you can't, since strings are immutable, you have to create a new string:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

You should use a method that returns a new string with the desired modification.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Remember, in managed and safe .Net, strings are immutable, so even if you could do the above, you'd really be creating a new copy of the string with the replacement.

If you are only replacing one character, a simple loop is probably your best bet.

However, if you are going to make multiple replacements, consider using a `StringBuilder`:

```
  string s = "abc";
  var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s);
  stringBuilder[1] = 'x';
  s = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: should be stringBuilder[1] = 'x' not stringBuilder[2]. This returns abx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in C#, as the string cannot be altered (just destroyed and recreated).  Have a look at the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9sxk6fy.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this if you're using some Linq

```
private string ConvertStr(string inStr , int inIndex , char inChar)
{
char[] tmp = inStr.ToCharArray();
tmp.SetValue(inChar , inIndex);
return new string(tmp);
}
```

That should let you replace whatever char you want with whatever char you want.

Answer (score 0):

What's about this?

```
string originalString = "abc";

        var index = 1;
        char charToReplace = 'x';

        var newString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", originalString.Substring(0, index), charToReplace, originalString.Substring(index + 1));
```

Comment: How about string newString = originalString.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, charToReplace)

Answer (score 0):

yes
in c# string can not be altered.

but we can try this

```
string s = "abc";
s = s.Replace('b', 'x');
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

answer will be "axc".
as this will replace the old string with new string.

Comment: But if the string contains several "b"s and you only want to replace the first, this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
string s = "abc";
//s = s.Remove([index of char, that you need to replace], 1).Insert([index of char, that you need to replace], [new char]);
s = s.Remove(1, 1).Insert(1, "x");
```